# Open .msg file in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

Is there a way to open an .msg file with Outlook in Windows Phone? The .msg file would come as an attachment to an e-mail or downloadable from a website. Right now it just says "Can't open attachment. There's no application associated with this file type". I searched the app store and the internet but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

.msg files are messages created or saved from Microsoft Outlook for Windows. The Windows Phone email viewer is not Outlook. It is a separate mail viewer and does not recognize .msg files. If there is an app that can recognize and handle .msg files, that app can be used to open it. As of the time of this question, there appears to be no app that has claimed that it can handle .msg files.

As a workaround, you could have your sender save their email messages as .html which Windows Phone can open with Internet Explorer.